# Is there a way to modify JS code in loaded webpage?

Tags: javascript, python, jquery, selenium

I have a webpage that uses JavaScript to implement some front-end logic. I want to modify the source code of some class method and make webpage executing it.
The code looks like this

```
function() {
function e(e, t, n, i, r, o) {
    var a = this;
    return a.y1 = parseInt(e, 10),
    a.x1 = parseInt(t, 10),
    a.x2 = parseInt(i, 10),
    a.y2 = parseInt(n, 10),
    (isNaN(a.y1) || isNaN(a.x1) || isNaN(a.x2) || isNaN(a.y2)) && errorHandler.msg("critical", new Error("Illegal parameter in position Constructor"), !0, {
        y1: e,
        x1: t,
        y2: n,
        x2: i,
        promotion: r
    }),
    a.can = o,
    a
}
"undefined" == typeof Screen && (Screen = {});
Screen.getNullMove = function() {
    return Screen.getMove(0, 0, 0, 0)
}
,
Screen.getMove = function(t, n, i, r, o) {
    o = o && o.toLowerCase();
    var a = Screen.translate.linear(t, n, i, r, o);
    return new e(t,n,i,r,o,a)
}
,
```

I tried to redefine Screen.getMove = function(t, n, i, r, o) using Selenium but after that it seems browser cannot recognize e(t,n,i,r,o,a) that it returns. Could something be done about it?

Comment: You can redefine a function at any point, provided you have access to the scope the function is defined in.  In this case, so long as `Screen` is accessable, you can assign `getMove` a new function at any time.

Comment: Why modify the source code when you could have different functions available to execute? As @Taplar said, you could just reassign getMove when necessary.

Comment: So overwrite it in the console?

Comment: `driver.execute_script("javascript function definition here")`

Comment: I'm new to JS and web in general, therefore consider something that seems straightforward to me. Tried to redefine Screen.getMove in the Chrome address line and broke everything completely, got "Uncaught Reference Error: e is not defined", and seemed that modified function was placed somewhere not where it's supposed to be.

Comment: @lolenker: It is likely the identifier `e` is defined as part of a function closure that is only accessible inside the original JavaScript file.